# C++ process time

Tags: c++

Is there a C++ equivalent of Python's time.process_time()?

I am wanting to print the current processing time of the algorithm I am creating.

```
while (steps < 100){
    //...
    std::cout << "Current processing time: " << process_time() << std::endl;
    //...
{
```

Output:

```
Current processing time: 10.431
Current processing time: 13.424
```

Comment: Have a look into [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono). Not exactly the same as `process_time()` but you can easily find out time taken for running the algorithm using this.

Comment: On Windows you can use GetProcessTimes to determine the time your process used the CPU (User  + kernel times are provided separately).